# Gerunds and Infinitives difference

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> 1)His dream is **to have a big house**.
>
> 2)His dream is **having a big house**

Are both the sentences correct? If yes, What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: What makes you think they are objects?

Comment: @BillJ I thought they are objects for verb dream. Aren’t they? If not, sorry for wrong heading. Please explain the differences

Comment: I see. Actually, the clauses are complements of "is". "Dream" is a noun, not a verb, Thus "his dream" = having/to have a big house.

Comment: @BillJ Thankyou , But what is the difference between having/to have a big house? That’s my main question

Comment: Both are grammatically OK, but the infinitival is perhaps more natural.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I would say that both sentences sound completely correct and they both mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thankyou. Could you please explain the difference between these two: 1)He knows swimming. 2)He knows how to swim.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought they are objects for verb dream.

*Is* is the verb, not *dream*.

Possessive determiners such as *my*, *our*, *his*, *her*, *their*, *X's*, like any other determiner, make the following word a noun, not a verb.

And usually English non-question sentences start with a noun, and the verb follows the noun, because of "Subject-Verb-Object" order.

*His dream* is actually the subject of the verb *is*, which is a form of *be*.

The verb *be* is in a category with a couple of verbs--such as *seem*, *like*, *become* and a few others--called copular verbs.

Copular verbs don't take objects; in the place that looks like an object for other verbs is what's called a *predicate nominatives* or *subject complements*.

- Predicate nominatives tell you the name of something.  *I am John* - *John* is a PN.
- Subject complements - in *X is Y*, if Y is a SC, Y tells you one or more attributes of X.  *The water is hot* - *hot* is a SC.

This is different than an object.  An object is the "target" of a verb, but words like *be* are more like "equal signs" than actions.

Here's an example of a verb that requires an object.

> I hit the wall

*The wall* is the object of *hit*.  You can't substitute an adjective for *the wall*, such as *hot*, because *hit* wants objects, not PNs or SCs.

Comment: but what is the difference between having a big house/ to have a big house